# Speed up MySQL insert stored procedure

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I am trying to speed up the process for inserting 1000s of records from a CSV. I have a contact table that joins to a contact phone table.

This is my pertinent SQL structure:

```
Contact Table
+----+-----------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+
| id | firstName | lastName |     primaryEmail | locationId | organizationId |
+----+-----------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+
|  1 |      John |      Doe | jdoe@noemail.com |          1 |              1 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+

Contact Phone Table
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+----------------+
| id | contactId |       number | primary | organizationId |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 | +15555555555 |       1 |              1 |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+----------------+
|  2 |         1 | +11231231234 |       0 |              1 |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+----------------+
```

I need to insert a new contact with a single phone that is set to primary if the phone and/or email doesn't exist already. Contacts can't have multiple phone numbers in the CSV but they can be updated manually after they are added.

This is the MySQL stored procedure I came up with

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `save_bulk_contact`(IN last_name VARCHAR(128), IN first_name VARCHAR(128), IN email VARCHAR(320), IN location_id BIGINT, IN organization_id BIGINT, IN phone_number VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN

    DECLARE CheckExists INT;
    DECLARE insert_id BIGINT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CheckExists FROM contact
    LEFT JOIN contact_phone ON contact.id = contact_phone.contactId
    WHERE contact.organizationId = organization_id 
        AND contact.locationId = location_id
        AND ((`primaryEmail` <> '' AND `primaryEmail` = email) OR `number` = phone_number);

    IF (CheckExists = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO contact
            (`lastName`, `firstName`, `primaryEmail`, `locationId`, `organizationId`)
        VALUE (last_name, first_name, email, location_id, organization_id);
        SET insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO contact_phone
            (`contactId`, `number`, `type`, `primary`, `organizationId`)
        VALUE (insert_id, phone_number, 'CELL', 1, organization_id);
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am using this stored procedure with Spring JDBC template batch update. Contact CSVs can contain 50,000+ contacts. I have tried many approaches to the problem and none of them seem great. This is another attempt: [Insert 1000s of records with relationship and ignore duplicates using JDBC & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865897/insert-1000s-of-records-with-relationship-and-ignore-duplicates-using-jdbc-mys) but I received no answers. I ran that Java heavy approach with a CSV file containing 100,000 contacts with about 5000 contacts already in my database and it took almost 3 hours.

I started a CSV upload of 50,000 contacts from my web app using the above stored procedure about 30 minutes ago or so. It has added about 23,000 of them thus far.

What can I do to make this process more efficient and finish more quickly?

Update: I just finished the 50,000 inserts and it took 1.7 hours.

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: Are you sure your `SELECT` query works correctly? Putting `number = phone_number` in the `WHERE` clause will filter out contacts that have no matching `contact_phone` row.

Comment: Yes. I am getting a count of records that do exist. If the number exists then I don't want to insert it. If there is no match then I need to insert. The prepared statement works as expected. It just takes forever.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? The only reason to use that is because you want to find rows in `contact` that don't have matches in `contact_phone`.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is slower than `INNER JOIN`, so you should not use it unless you actually need to.

Comment: I need to count all contacts that match by phone or email. I need the left join because they may exist with an email address but no phone number. If I do an inner join then it will only find matches that have phone regardless of their email address.

Comment: Do you have any idea if the "check exists" or the insert is taking up the most time?  Also, what do your indexes look like on the two above tables?

Answer (score 0):

First.  Add indexes to organization id and location id in both tables if not already there. Break out your check exists into two statements to use Inner join and get rid of the "OR"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CheckExists FROM contact
INNER JOIN contact_phone ON contact.id = 
contact_phone.contactId
WHERE contact.organizationId = organization_id 
    AND contact.locationId = location_id
    AND ((`primaryEmail` <> '' AND `primaryEmail` = email);

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CheckExistsTwo FROM contact
INNER JOIN contact_phone ON contact.id = 
contact_phone.contactId
WHERE contact.organizationId = organization_id 
    AND contact.locationId = location_id
    AND  `number` = phone_number;

IF (CheckExists = 0 OR CheckExistsTwo = 0)
```